# How to count how many hits for a given id in the second table

Tags: sql, count, left-join

I have 3 tables like "brands" and "whisky" and "country"

**BRANDS**

```
brand_id   brand_name      brand_country_id
1          Example brand   1
2          Brand 2         2
```

**Whisky**

```
whisky_id   whisky_brand_id
1           2
2           2
3           1
4           2
```

**Country**

```
country_id  country_nicename
1           Poland
2           Germany
```

And i have SQL:

```
SELECT
    brands.brand_id,
    brands.brand_name,
    brands.brand_country_id,
    country.country_id,
    country.country_niename
FROM
    brands
LEFT JOIN
    country
ON
    brands.brand_country_id = country.country_id
LEFT JOIN
    whisky
ON
    brands.brand_id = whisky.whisky_brand_id
```

I'm want to data like

```
brand_id brand_name country_id country_nicename no.ofWhisky
2        Brand2     1          Germany          3
```

But i dont know how to count no of whisky in this query :/ 
can anyone help? 
Thx :)

Comment: SELECT brands.brand_id, brands.brand_name, brands.brand_country_id, country.country_id, country.country_niename ,temp.whiskycount
FROM brands LEFT JOIN country ON brands.brand_country_id = country.country_id 
LEFT JOIN (
select count(*) as whiskycount, whisky_brand_id
from whisky
Group by whisky_brand_id
) temp ON brands.brand_id = whisky.whisky_brand_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to do aggregation using `group by` & `count()`:

```
SELECT brands.brand_id, brands.brand_name, country.country_id, country.country_niename, 
       count(whisky_id) as no.ofWhisky
FROM brands LEFT JOIN 
     country 
     ON brands.brand_country_id = country.country_id LEFT JOIN 
     whisky 
     ON brands.brand_id = whisky.whisky_brand_id
GROUP BY brands.brand_id, brands.brand_name, country.country_id, country.country_niename;
```

Comment: LOL if it is so simple, then it will be better if I stop programming. Thx works ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT brands.brand_id, brands.brand_name, brands.brand_country_id, country.country_id, country.country_niename ,temp.whiskycount
FROM brands LEFT JOIN country ON brands.brand_country_id = country.country_id 
LEFT JOIN (
select count(*) as whiskycount, whisky_brand_id
from whisky
Group by whisky_brand_id
) temp ON brands.brand_id = whisky.whisky_brand_id
```